# Any way to see my own google ad?

Tags: google, google-ads

I am working on Google Adwords and I'm really new to this ads stuff, I need to see my ad, and I'm unable to see the ad when I type the keywords it doesn't show my ad. I don't want its preview or anything. I want real search ads, like the ones that are displayed before the search result. Is there any way that I can see my ad in search and click it, is there some functionality or tool that I don't know about? or any other method? What I have already done is that, I have written the keywords that are shown in the Google Adwords account, but my ad doesn't show up.

Comment: In the future please try to use proper grammar and punctuation in your text.

Answer (score 3):

Google has an [ad preview tool](https://adwords.google.com/apt/anon/AdPreview) for this purpose.

It allows you to set the targeting to ensure that your ad shows up to the correct users.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have setup your ad only to Google search and not to Google Display network?. GDN ads display on other website who are using Adsense ads. Normally it is cheaper than search ads.

There are already too many advertiser bid on same keyword like you did, so there are many of factor play a major role like your bid rate, your budget and absolutely your targeting option. You should check your status of ads, just see weather your ads is eligible or not from your campaign dashboard. If it is eligible then I am sure you will get some impression on your ads, then you can get the list of keywords on which you're getting impression, then you can use that keywords to check your live ads on Search.

But again you may be not seen your own ads, and it is because you may not targeting people like you. I mean by geo location, age, male or female etc.

[Adwords help center](https://support.google.com/adwords) might be good choice to learn more about it.